# Parse multipart/form-data json body of lambda in Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, java-8, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to implement a Lambda function that receives a POST request containing data encoded as multipart/form-data. The message is received through the API Gateway using Lambda Proxy integration and the body is encoded in Base64 when it arrives to the Lambda function. After decoding it manually, I see it contains a multipart body like the following:

```
-----WebKitFormBoundary3EZ0C3tbP2JpAmz4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"

value1
-----WebKitFormBoundary3EZ0C3tbP2JpAmz4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param2"

value2
------WebKitFormBoundary3EZ0C3tbP2JpAmz4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="ivr.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG
... [binary stuff]
------WebKitFormBoundary3EZ0C3tbP2JpAmz4--
```

What I need is to parse this message in java 8.
so that I can access the individual parts like

```
1. form data 
2  file content
```

I have tried fileupload, Apache Multipart those didn't workout

Any sols will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with my application. I used and modified a custom form-data parser here: https://apimeister.com/2015/10/10/formdatahandler-implements-com-sun-net-httpserver-httphandler.html

I got it to parse properly however, the binary data came in malformed similar to this issue here: https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/230

How did you get the entire AWS Lambda body to encode to base64? Can you post instructions to do so? That may fix the malformed data issue I am running into.

Comment: i have specified as multipart/form-data in mapping template at Lambda Proxy integration Request in API Gateway, It directly convert your body data to base64 format.

Comment: Ah nice, I'll look into it. Let me know if you need help implementing that form-data parser. It pretty much depends on how you setup your RequestHandler for your Lambda function, you can modify it pretty easily to get it to work. I'll let you know what I come up with base64 the entire body.